# Convert the Sas mdy function to sql in yymmdd format

Tags: sql, sas, type-conversion

We are having a sas code which contain mdy function.i want to convert that function to sql in yymmdd format.

Can anyone help.

Sas code:
If day(&x.)<12 and month(&x.)=1 then call symputx('date_boundary',put(mdy(10,1,year(&x.)-1),date.));

The date should be in yyyymmdd format

Comment: But which flavour of SQL? (i.e. which dbms is actually used?)  date handling syntax differs considerably for each SQL implementation. Please choose the correct tag.

Comment: Snowpark can u convert

Comment: What is the value in the macro variable `x` ?  How is the macro variable `date_boundary` planned to be used later on ?  Will it be in a SQL pass-through query ?  Will it be part of a SAS SQL query against a table in a remote database library (Snowpark) ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need `select into` statement and macro conditional statement `%if ... %then`:

```
%if %sysfunc(day(&x.))<12 and %sysfunc(month(&x.))=1 %then %do;
proc sql noprint;
  select put(mdy(10,1,year(&x.)-1),yymmddn8.) into :date_boundary from sashelp.class;
quit;
%end;
```

As for the yyyymmdd format, you can use `yymmddn8.` or `b8601da8.`.